# How to add images webservice?

Tags: smartface.io

I have a web-service which accepts image data.Anyone guide me how do I sent image file which I have captured from my phone to the services on a button click?. I searched the smartface docs and also the website I got an idea of uploading to a Web-client but didn't find anything of how to upload data to SOAP services.

Thanks.

Comment: Please identify the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of data does your webservice except.

If you are using capture function of camare, you will be able to reach the path of photo.
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/device/camera-usage-2/#capture

Also, you can save the captured photo, and use it by the name you gived. 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/device/camera-usage-2/#save

If these documents don't help, can you share the url of service in order for me to check it?

Comment: My webservice except's byte data and that byte data is converted to image by webservice. So how should I send the image byte data to the webservice?@merve

Comment: guide me through @mervebıçakçı